# Creating customer ID out of max id while testing min string length in Do While Statement in php

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

I am creating a basic customer management system for an admin panel and need to create a new id number for each new customer but I want it to run off the row id in the DB. I am checking what the last id number is then adding one to it however. The customer id number goes as follows: 000001, 000002, so forth and so on.

In the script below I first test for MAX customer id from table and fetch the associated data, store the customer id into a variable and then add 1 to the variable result. this is where a small portion of the issue begins. The result after adding is a single digit instead of a 6 digit result such as 000003 for example. I get 3 instead. I then add padding in 0's to the end result with str_pad(); so that I can add the additional 5 0's I need to create the customer number.

The big problem begins when I try to add the while statement. I keep getting this:
 "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ..."

I am assuming this is because the while statement is somehow creating an endless loop. Any thoughts on what can fix this? I tried it 3 different ways but I keep getting the fatal error when I do the "do... while loop". Thanks

```
do{
            if($result = $dbConnection->query("SELECT MAX(customerId) AS customerId FROM customers")){
                $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $itemId2 = $data['customerId'];
                $customerId = $itemId2 + 1;
            }
            $customerId = str_pad($customerId, 1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        } while(strlen($customerId) < 5);
```

Comment: the problem is you're selecting the max id, good, adding one to it, good, but then you're trying to left pad it with zero's one at a time, bad! the loop should be around the str_pad not the entire db call and what have you

Comment: infact just change the str_pad length to 5 and you're done

Comment: Makes me wonder why didn't you simply use unique key id as a database column and always have a unique customer id?
It would have also made it easier to select, join, cascade etc with other tables.

Comment: I see what you mean however, if I change the str_pad length to 5 what will happen after the DB id gets to 10? The customer id will no longer be 6 digits but 7. For the time being I was trying to keep the Cust. ID at 6 digits so I thought looping while adding the 0 digits till 6 characters would have been a good simple option. Would you say it is better to simply use the DB id as a customer number since they are unique?

Comment: @MauroTamm Yes you are right. I think that will be my option instead. Thanks for the help to both of you.

Comment: Also if you need a formatted id  like 00034  - you can do that  after selecting the unique id from database.
`sprintf('%05d', $number)` - would add 2 zeros if the number is 123, 1 zero if its 1234 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sprintf('%06d', 1231);
```

06 means it will be a 6 digit string, it will add 2 leading zeros to 1231.
Can be adjusted for max length.
May want to cast back to integer if it's important.